# What statistical test should I use? Mixed ANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, manova

I am testing the effectiveness of an intervention. I have 3 groups of participants (age 5, 10, 15), who will be randomly assigned to either intervention group or control group. I will conduct the intervention for three times and measure their 4 test scores over time to see if this intervention is effective. What statistical test should I use?

Comment: @DevonOliver, you are right that the MANOVA is a multivariate ANOVA, but it can be used for a repeated measures analysis, & people sometimes prefer it.

Comment: You say they have 4 scores, @Avery, is everyone measured at baseline & then at three follow-ups post-intervention?